# Decode attributes in url

Tags: php, utf-8

I have an e-shop with a filter module. Some options in filter module are in Greek characters.

When someone selects a filter like this then in url an attribute is added with a format like this:

```
&attribute_value[12][]=Υπολογιστές
```

but the user sees in url this:

```
&attribute_value%5B12%5D%5B%5D%3D%CE%A5%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AD%CF%82
```

I have found the query in php fucntion that returns the attributes but is there a way to decode attributes before printed in url when user selects the attribute from filtering?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [`urldecode($variable)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: A URL cannot contain the plain string "Υπολογιστές", it *must* be encoded. However, since even the `=` seems to be encoded in your case it seems like improper encoding is happening at some point. You'll have to clarify what exactly is encoding what here.

Comment: Generally in my url i have Greek characters showing normal. The characters are encoded when i copy paste the link but visitors see greek characters fine in url. So, can i somehow decode characters before showing to url?

Comment: The URL *must* be encoded to be a valid URL; the browser *may* display it in a decoded format if it chooses to do so, but that's entirely up to the browser and not something you can decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rawurldecode`                                                 .

```
<?php

rawurldecode('&attribute_value%5B12%5D%5B%5D%3D%CE%A5%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AD%CF%82')

//out put: &attribute_value[12][]=Υπολογιστές
```